# Partition function of an Ideal monoatomic relativistic gas | Solving an integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, statistical-mechanics

I'm interested on finding the partition function $Z(\beta)$ of an ideal monoatomic relativistic gas.  The partition function $Z(\beta)$ is given for this case as

$$Z(\beta) \equiv \prod\limits_i^{N_A} Z_i(\beta) \qquad \wedge \qquad  Z_i(\beta) = k \int dq_1 dq_2 ... dq_N \int dp_1 dp_2 ... dp_N e^{-\beta H(\{\ q_i, p_i\})}$$

For one particle moving in coordinates $q_i$ with momentum $p_i$. The parameter $\beta$ is simply $\beta \equiv 1/k_B T$, and $H$, the Hamiltonian, follows the form $H = \sqrt{m^2c^4 + m^2p^2}$  , where $\vec{p} = \sum\limits_i^N p_i \hat{x_i}$  , e.g., in 2-dim $\vec{p}\cdot \vec{p} = (p_x \hat{i} + p_y \hat{j})\cdot (p_x \hat{i} + p_y \hat{j}) = p_x^2 + p_y^2$.

In the simplest case the integral is

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp{\left(-\beta \sqrt{m^2c^4 + p_x^2c^2}\right)} \,dp_x$$

As $\vec{p} = \gamma m \vec{v} \; \| \; \gamma \equiv (1-v^2/c^2)^{-1/2}$ with $v<c$, in the limit $v \to c$, $p$ goes to $\infty$

Do you know any "trick" to tackle the problem?

I'm thinking on expressing $H$ as $H = mc^2 \sqrt{1+(p/mc)^2}$ and replacing $x\equiv p/mc$. Then, assuming that $p << mc$ I could expand to 2nd order in a Taylor series around $x_0 =0$ but I find this not as rigurous as I'd like it to be.

Any hint?

Comment: By "solve" the integral, what kind of form would you like to express it as? It seems likely to me that the definite integral cannot be expressed using elementary functions. Also, you cannot use a small $p$ approximation in general, because you must integrate $p$ across all microstates, including those of arbitrarily large energy (a.k.a. arbitrarily large momentum).

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong If there's no way to generalize a solution, maybe finding a closed-form expression for the case dim=3 ($\vec{p} = p_x \hat{i} + p_y \hat{j} + p_z \hat{k}$), so I can calculate thermodynamic quantities such as the entropy S, heat capacity, expected energy of the system, etc... which are derivatives of $Z(\beta)$ or $ln Z(\beta)$

Comment: I'm not sure about the 3-dimensional case, but for the 2-dimensional case you can use a polar substitution $p_1 = r \cos{\theta}, p_2 = r \sin{\theta}$, and $dp_1 dp_2 = r dr d\theta$, and from there one should be able to directly evaluate the integral by substitution. That being said, I feel that the integral is itself already a pretty nice form, so you may try to consider calculating your thermodynamic quantities directly from the integral you've written out already.

Comment: You may find the exercise found [here](http://www.phys.uri.edu/gerhard/PHY525/wtex91.pdf) of relevance. It's an exercise and so does not establish the formulas stated, but may provide a lead on such. In particular, the best one can seem to hope for in the 3D case is to express it in terms of a modified Bessel function.

Answer (score 1):

In the 2-dim case, as @ChristopherA.Wong mentioned, it's simple to evaluate directly the integral by substitution.

Let

$$Z_i(\beta) = \frac{1}{h^2} \int dq_x dq_y \, \int dp_x dp_y \, e^{-\beta\,\sqrt{m^2 c^4 + m^2 p^2}}$$

where $dq_x dq_y$ is simply $dA$. Changing to polar coordinates:

$$p_x = r\,\cos{\theta} \qquad p_y = r\, \sin{\theta} \qquad \rightarrow \vec{p} \cdot \vec{p} = r^2 \, \big| \, r>0$$

it follows:

$$Z_i(\beta) = \frac{1}{h^2}\int dA \,\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\infty} r dr d\theta \, e^{-\beta mc^2 \sqrt{1 + (\vec{p}/mc)^2}} = \frac{A}{h^2} \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \, \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\beta mc^2 \sqrt{1+(r/mc)^2}} r dr$$

and from u-sub: $1 + (r/mc)^2 \to x$:

$$Z_i(\beta) = \frac{2\pi A}{h^2} \int_1^\infty \frac{m^2 c^2}{2} e^{-\beta mc^2 \sqrt{x}}  \, dx = \frac{\pi A m^2 c^2}{h^2} \int_1^{\infty} e^{\zeta \sqrt{x}} dx \; \Big| \; \zeta \equiv -\beta mc^2$$

Finally, integrating by parts:

\begin{align*}
    \int_1^{\infty} e^{\zeta \sqrt{x}} dx &= \int_\zeta^{\infty} e^u \, \frac{2 u}{\zeta^2 } \,du = \frac{2}{\zeta^2} \int_\zeta^\infty u e^u du\\
    &= \frac{2}{\zeta^2} \left(u\, e^u \Big|_\zeta^\infty - \int_\zeta^\infty e^u du\right) = \frac{2}{\zeta^2}\left(e^u (u -1)\right)\big|_\zeta^\infty \\
    &= - \frac{2\, e^\zeta\, (\zeta-1)}{\zeta^2} = \frac{2\, e^{-\beta mc^2 }(1+ mc^2 \beta)}{(\beta m c^2)^2}
\end{align*}

from where $Z(\beta)$ can be easily computed.

then

$$\boxed{Z_i(\beta) = \frac{2\pi A}{h^2 \beta^2 c^2}e^{-\beta mc^2 }(1+ mc^2 \beta)}$$

Comment: This will solve the 2 - dim problem although it's not enough to generalize the result. I'd expect a method to solve for dim $\geq 3$